# XNA Decrease variable as time decreases

Tags: xna

I effectively have a health bar that I want to deplete each second that goes by. The rate at which the bar depletes is declared in another variable which will change depending on actions taken by the player within the game.

Any tips on how to use GameTime on how to achieve this?

Comment: Show us some code please.

Comment: That's the problem I'm having, I'm not entirely sure how to start coding the time part. Below is a small bit of pseudo code explaining how it would work. 

while (health > 0)
 {
 when gametime increases by 1 second
 health -= decrease rate
 }

Any tutorials I could use to understand the GameTime Properties, Methods etc. would also be a big help (aside from MSDN, I don't find it very helpful)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that you may find helpful.  First we will declare a few variables in order to set the time intervals we want to work with:

```
float timer = 3;
float const TIMER = 3;     //We also declare a const for resetting purposes
```

In your update method, you can extract the elapsed time since the last update (delta time) as follows:

```
float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
```

Still in your update method, you can now subtract the elapsed time with your timer variable:

```
timer -= elapsed;
```

Now you just need to check if your timer is expired, and then run code:

```
if (timer < 0)
{
    if (health > 0)
    {
        health -= rate;
        timer += TIMER;   //reset timer
    }
}
```

And that is how I would do it.

Comment: @user2429279 I didn't mention it in the response, however, the code states TotalSeconds, therefore, the timer we set is in seconds.  using the above code verbatim, would provide you with a 3 second timer.

Comment: Yep, I got that bit, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment on Jon's answer I'll just add a comment to his post as a reply. You might want to use "timer += TIMER", else you'll lose out on fractional parts of the time. That is, 3.2 seconds will turn into 3 seconds.

Comment: Good point.  This would be a more accurate timer.  I updated my code.

Comment: Okay thanks! Why is it that time is lost using Jon's original method?

Comment: @AJCol
For a simple example, let's assume each update takes 0.4s. Game starts, timer is a 3.0 and the timer counts down: 2.6, 2.2, ..., 0.6, 0.2, -0.2, meaning the total time taken for the health bar to adjust is 3.2s. If you set the timer to 3.0 again the procedure will repeat; the health bar will adjust every 3.2s. If you instead use += the timer will be set to 2.8s (-0.2 + 3.0 = 2.8), and the sequence goes 2.4, 2.0, ..., 0.4, 0.0. This time it actually took 2.8s. This will repeat (3.2s, 2.8s, 3.2s etc), for an average of 3.0s instead of 3.2s.

Comment: Oh, and it should be "if (timer <= 0)".